# How to map Sharepoint 365 to network drive using VB script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, vba

I am trying to map SharePoint Online 365 to network drive using VB script for my UFT test.

Below is my test script. It used to work but the files need to be transferred to SharePoint online 365 and now its not working anymore. It doesn't get mapped. Can anyone help me please.

Thank you!

```
'Create FSO and network object
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objFSO= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'call Fucntion to create network drive
networkDrive= fnMapNetworkDrive()

'Map the sharePoint folder to the free Drive-Letter
objNet.MapNetworkDrive networkDrive,sharepointFolder,false,UserName,Pwd
```

Comment: What error you are getting ??

Comment: @Karthik Actually there is no error coming up. Before, I used to map SharePoint 2010 to my local machine using the above script. When I run the above script, SharePoint will be in my list of my network locations. However, now I need to map SharePoint Online 365 to my local machine. When I run the above script, SharePoint is not appearing in the list of my network locations which means the script above is not working with the SharePoint Online 365.

Comment: There is other way to map your SharePoint online libraries to network drives, https://bauensolutions.com/2017/01/20/how-to-map-your-sharepoint-online-library-like-a-network-drive/ , Hope that helps